# If A fails to pay C under a contract between A and B to do so, can C sue A?

Tags: contract-law, standing

A promises B to pay C a sum of money, say Rs.500. However, A does not pay the amount to C.

Can C take legal action against A for non-performance?

Comment: Because C is a [beneficiary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-party_beneficiary) to the contract between A and B, C *may* have a cause of action, but this depends on the nature of the contract and the jurisdiction. For more information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privity_of_contract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody can take action against A. In order for anybody to obligate A, they must give something to A, which is not the case here (there has to be "consideration"). In this case, we don't even know if B is alive or A and B speak the same language. You can make a promise to a tree, or to a person who doesn't understand you. Only an agreement can be binding, and we have no evidence that there is any meeting of the minds, or even a second mind. You can remedy this, e.g. A promises B to pay C Rs. 500 if B gives him an egg. C could not sue unless the local law recognised a third-party beneficiary right to sue (this right is apparently not recognized in India, but is in the UK). Since C didn't (given the fact in front of us) rely on this promise, there will be no suit. But perhaps C could fix that by releasing B from an obligation to return a hatchet based on the Rs. 500, and also by being sure that this all took place in the UK. Or, you could remedy this by making C part of the agreement, so that A has a contract with B and C.

Comment: Not necessarily. C is a [third-party beneficiary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-party_beneficiary) to the contract.

Comment: There's always a tweak.